# Maximal values of axes in a GraphView

Tags: java, android, graph, android-graphview

I have the following code:

```
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(arr);
                graphView.addSeries(series);
                graphView.getViewport().setMaxX(31);
                graphView.getViewport().setMaxY(150);
                graphView.getViewport().setMinX(1);
                graphView.getViewport().setMinY(0);
```

I need to set maximal and minimal values of axises by this code, but when I run the program I have this values:

[image]

What's the matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [javadoc](http://jjoe64.github.io/GraphView/javadoc/com/jjoe64/graphview/Viewport.html#setMaxY-double-):

> Make sure to set the y bounds to manual via setYAxisBoundsManual(boolean)

So you must also add

```
graphView.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
graphView.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
```